# Is there a way to determine if a variable passed in is reference type or value type?

Tags: swift

In Swift, is there a way to determine through code if a variable passed in is reference type or value type?

For example, is tuple a value type or reference type?

Comment: And how do you define "reference type" and "value type"?

Comment: @newacct Value type gets copied at var/let declaration or when passed to a function, reference type does not.

Comment: All types get copied. In Swift, everything is assign by value and pass by value unless the parameter is `inout`. For reference types, the value is a reference (pointer), and that is what's copied. But a type can be composite and contain pointer and non-pointer components. Then what do you call it?

Comment: @newacct Swift does not use pointer internally for reference type.

Comment: What do you think "reference" type means? Reference = pointer. You can call it what you like.

Comment: This is like saying C++ reference is the same as pointer.  It's not the same.  Reference means it refers to the object, but in Swift it is not a direct pointer to a memory address like it is in C.

Comment: C++ "reference" is not what most languages call a "reference". In Java, a "reference" is defined in the language specification as a pointer to an object. It is also semantically identical to a pointer to an object in C++. Same with references in Swift. Same with references in Python, Ruby, and most other languages.

Comment: I have pointed out very clearly above that in Swift, a reference is not a direct pointer to a memory address like in C, so you cannot say it's a pointer because it's not the same.  It's the same as pointer in that they are both reference types.

Comment: And how is it *not* "a direct pointer to a memory address"? How is it semantically distinguishable?

Comment: C implements reference as pointer, which is a direct pointer to a memory address, it's not so in Swift.

Comment: I ask you again, how is a semantically distinguishable? If it is not semantically distinguishable, then it is semantically the same thing.

Comment: Pointer is internal implementation, that's why you can use the copy by value argument, but that's not valid for Swift.  And you cannot use semantically indistinguishable to further confuse implementation detail with a concept (reference) and infer that reference must be copy by value under the hood as well.

Comment: Pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are language semantics terms, and are independent of implementation. According to your logic, we cannot infer that references in Java are copied when they are passed. But look anywhere on Stack Overflow or elsewhere and they will tell you everything in Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: Understood but there is nothing in what I said that infers Java's reference cannot be copied by value.  I am suggesting that we should stop confusing the issue of what is a reference type vs value type by hinting at the notion that Swift uses pointer under the hood (which it is not), which then further implies its value be copied when passed to a function, muddying the concept of reference type vs value type, because Swift's reference internal implementation is different than C's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Everything* is a value type except for:

- An instance of a class
- A function
- An array (which works in an odd way; it is passed by reference but can become unbound from its other avatars if it is mutable and the number of items is changed)

The simple code way to test is just to assign to two different `var` names, change one, and see if they are still equal. For example:

```
    var tuple1 = (1,2)
    var tuple2 = tuple1
    tuple1.1 = 3
    println(tuple1)
    println(tuple2)
```

They are *different*, proving that a tuple is passed by *value*. But:

```
    var arr1 = [1,2]
    var arr2 = arr1
    arr1[1] = 3
    println(arr1)
    println(arr2)
```

They are *the same*, proving that an array is passed by *reference*.

**EDIT:**

But in **beta 3** of Swift, this unusual behavior of Array is withdrawn, and only class instances and functions are passed by reference. Everything else is passed by value now.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, array is value type.

Comment: @Boon array is `struct`. but it is implemented as reference type (like C array / pointer).

Comment: @BryanChen Doc says this: “integers, floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, arrays and dictionaries—are value types, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.” Its copy behavior may be different than a standard value type in that it only copies when its size change, but it's not a reference type just because of this difference, no?

Comment: depends how you define reference type. like some say `NSArray *` is reference type. but _pointer_ can be categorized as value type because pointer itself is pass by value. same for swift Array. it is pass by value, but what copied is just a pointer (kind of). the content is pass by reference.

Comment: Because Swift does not use pointer internally in the C-sense (a block of memory containing a direct memory address), whether internally it requires the copying of the memory address or not is really implementation detail so should not be involved in the definition of reference type vs value type.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, to pass by reference you need to add the `inout` keyword in front of the parameter definition. all other parameters are constants unless prefixed with the `var` keyword

> “Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the value of a function parameter from within the body of that function results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the value of a parameter by mistake.”

and...

> “Variable parameters, as described above, can only be changed within the function itself. If you want a function to modify a parameter’s value, and you want those changes to persist after the function call has ended, define that parameter as an in-out parameter instead.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: I don't mean pass by reference.  I mean if something is a reference type vs value type (like array, dictionary and struct are value types)

Comment: misunderstood the question. i think everything is value type except classes and closures