# is tuple a value type or reference type in Swift?

Tags: swift, tuples

I know that in Swift struct and enum are value types, classes and functions are reference type. But what about tuple types? I searched Apple's book Swift programming language 3.0 but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Please visit, I think it will help you - https://whatilearnedtoday.io/swift-tuples/

Comment: Hi Tony. As I may have mentioned before to you, there is no need to add a "please help" boilerplate to all of your questions. Since it is obvious you need help, it can be interpreted as a form of begging. Volunteers prefer succinct to hurrying here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple test demonstrates that tuples are value types:

```
var tuple1 = (1, 2)
var tuple2 = tuple1
tuple1.0 = 3
print("t1 = \(tuple1), t2 = \(tuple2)")
```

Output:

> t1 = (3, 2), t2 = (1, 2)

If tuples were reference types, `tuple2` would have been changed.

Comment: And I just now saw [matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24439640/1226963) from the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439471/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-variable-passed-in-is-reference-type-or-value-t) proposed by kennytm. I wrote my nearly duplicate answer before ever seeing his code. Eerie.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I saw matt's answer too, thanks to kennytm. I guess great minds think alike :P

Comment: Alternatively, that `let x = ( 1, 2 ) ; x.1 = 3` generates an immutable value error, also argues that it's a value type.